# apache2 vhost redirection

Tags: apache2, redirect, virtual-hosts

I have defined differents hosts in my windows host file, one for every project release (rc1, rc2 etc..)
I would like to create one vhost per release so I can redirect directly to its subdir, for example :

pp15.mv => http://localhost/mv/pp15/.....
pp16.mv => http://localhost/mv/pp16/.....

moreover, I need to redirect the host ppX.mv to an autologin url, something looks like **/mv_dbname.php?login=testlogin&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70**

so, finally, I want to type this in my urlbar :
http://pp15.mv
and get redirected to
http://pp15.mv/mv_dbname.php?login=testlogin&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70

In my virtual host file I have something like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pp15.mv
    DocumentRoot "D:\apache\htdocs\mv\pp15"
    <Directory "D:\apache\htdocs\mv\pp15">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/index.php /myvisitv3_dbname.php?login=johsmi&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 [R]
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /myvisitv3_dbname.php?login=johsmi&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

The first redirection works great, but if i try to redirect directly the host, I get a redirection error (too many redirections occured)

Do someone have an idea ?

Thank you previously.

Comment: Just looking at that virtual host you have only setup the rewrite rule for requests on the domain pp15.mv. Were you trying to access the redirect for a domain other than this? As far as I'm aware, you would still need to have virtual hosts (or at least aliases) for the other domains, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I only trying to access from the pp15.mv domain, I haven't listed any vhost that I have, just one for example, the other are quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

ok, finally here what I did :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pp16.mv
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pp16\.mv$ 
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /mv/pp16/xxx/xxx_dbname.php?login=johsmi&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

no [L] on redirection because app have internal redirection, and no document root because php won't be able to read **$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI']** var correctly, so I could have did this (I prefer)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pp16.mv
    DocumentRoot "D:\apache\htdocs\mv\pp16\xxx"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pp16\.mv$ 
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /xxx_dbname.php?login=johsmi&mdp=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

but php would have misread the app path (**/** instead of **/mv/pp16/xxx/**)